# Node.js wont let me console.log?

Tags: node.js

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var urls = [];


request('http://www.reddit.com', function(err, resp,body){
    if(err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('a.title','#siteTable').each(function(){     //where they are located
            var url = this.attr('href');
            urls.push(url);
        });
        console.log(urls);   // print them
    }
});
```

System: Mac

Note: I have installed `request` and `cheerio`.

After I have compiled this program, with no errors. The main purpose of this program is to request to a site and then find each "href" in the html page and its data. The problem is, that no data is being outputted. Could someone explain it to me. thanks in advance.

------Unexpected output ---------

`C:\Users\*****\Documents>node test.js`
No data is printed from the website, in html form.

`C:\Users\******\Documents>`

------Expected Ouput -------------------------

`C:\Users\*****\Documents>node test.js`

`Web Site data printed.`

`C:\Users\******\Documents>`

Comment: Try to console.log outside of your if statement.

Comment: if you have error and if you have a 200 OK response you want to log. Not gonna happen unless Chuck Norris wants that way.

Comment: @gustavohenke thank you i see what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone kindly points out in the comments, the suspect line is:

```
if(err && resp.statusCode == 200)
```

err is probably undefined or null, so this if never evaluates to true.  You could change it to:

```
if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200)
```

But I would probably recommend you split the logic out here, and also use === rather than ==

```
if (err) {
    // do something to handle the err
}

if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
   // the rest of your logic.
}
```